# Close open CSV before writing data back to it. Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a csv file like so:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\data.csv"
```

Followed by code that formats the csv data.

When I write to the file

```
$csv | Export-Csv -path "C:\data.csv" -NoType
```

If the file is open I get (predictably)

```
**Export-Csv : The process cannot access the file 'C:\data.csv' because it is being used by another process.**
```

There are times the file may be saved yet remain open when interacting with the script. I'd like to efficiently check for the open file and close it so I can write the data back to the same file/variable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP had the file opened in Excel which adds the block. Nothing to do with Import or Export-Csv.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there is nothing like closing file in Powershell as it handles it automatically. Below code worked for me

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\data.csv"
$csv | Export-Csv -path "C:\data.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the file is open in Excel. When open in Notepad++ I do not have the issue.